# fill missing rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a data frame shown below

```
   Hair   Eye    Freq
1  Black Brown      32
2  Brown Brown      53
3    Red Brown      10
4  Blond Brown       3
5    Red  Blue      10
6  Blond  Blue      30
7  Black Hazel      10
8  Blond Hazel       5
```

In the above data frame frequency of  4 hair colors `Black, Brown, Red and Blond` are noted across different eye colors `Brown, Blue and Hazel`. However, I would like to fill in the missing hair color frequency for respective eye color so that it results in a data frame as below. Any help is appreciated.

```
   Hair   Eye    Freq
1  Black Brown      32
2  Brown Brown      53
3    Red Brown      10
4  Blond Brown       3
5  Black  Blue      0
6  Brown  Blue      0
7    Red  Blue      10
8  Blond  Blue      30
9  Black Hazel      10
10 Brown Hazel      0
11   Red Hazel      0
12 Blond Hazel      5
```

Comment: @akrun added a python target as well now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `R`, one option is `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
complete(df1, Hair, Eye, fill = list(Freq = 0)) %>%
      arrange(factor(Eye, levels = unique(df1$Eye)), factor(Hair, levels = unique(df1$Hair)))
# A tibble: 12 × 3
#    Hair   Eye  Freq
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1  Black Brown    32
#2  Brown Brown    53
#3    Red Brown    10
#4  Blond Brown     3
#5  Black  Blue     0
#6  Brown  Blue     0
#7    Red  Blue    10
#8  Blond  Blue    30
#9  Black Hazel    10
#10 Brown Hazel     0
#11   Red Hazel     0
#12 Blond Hazel     5
```

Comment: you are a gem. I spent all day...you made it look very simple. Never heard complete function. Thank you

Comment: why is it required to use `list(Freq = 0)` and not just `Freq = 0`. ?

Comment: @user5249203  I think it is to consider for multiple variables

Answer (score 2):

Create a new table with combinations of hair and eye colors using `expand.grid`. Then use join approach to bind the frequencies of `df1` to `df2`. Finally remove NAs.

```
library('data.table')
hair <- c('Black', 'Brown', 'Red', 'Blond')  # hair colors
eye <- c('Brown', 'Blue', 'Hazel')           # eye colors
df2 <- expand.grid(Hair = hair, Eye = eye)   # data frame with combinations of eye and hair colors
setDT(df2)[df1, `:=` (Freq = i.Freq), on = .(Hair, Eye)]  # join df2 with df1 based `on = .(Hair, Eye)` and bind `Freq` from df1 to df2
df2[is.na(Freq), Freq := 0 ]                # remove NA with 0
```

**Output:**

```
df2
#     Hair   Eye Freq
# 1: Black Brown   32
# 2: Brown Brown   53
# 3:   Red Brown   10
# 4: Blond Brown    3
# 5: Black  Blue    0
# 6: Brown  Blue    0
# 7:   Red  Blue   10
# 8: Blond  Blue   30
# 9: Black Hazel   10
# 10: Brown Hazel    0
# 11:   Red Hazel    0
# 12: Blond Hazel    5
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- fread('id   Hair   Eye    Freq
1  Black Brown      32
2  Brown Brown      53
3    Red Brown      10
4  Blond Brown       3
5    Red  Blue      10
6  Blond  Blue      30
7  Black Hazel      10
8  Blond Hazel       5')

df1[, id:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 2):

One base R option is to create another data frame with `expand.grid` for every combination of `Hair` and `Eye` and `merge` it with the original one.

```
merge(expand.grid(Hair=unique(df$Hair),Eye=unique(df$Eye)), df[-1], all.x = TRUE)

#    Hair   Eye Freq
#1  Black  Blue   NA
#2  Black Brown   32
#3  Black Hazel   10
#4  Blond  Blue   30
#5  Blond Brown    3
#6  Blond Hazel    5
#7  Brown  Blue   NA
#8  Brown Brown   53
#9  Brown Hazel   NA
#10   Red  Blue   10
#11   Red Brown   10
#12   Red Hazel   NA
```

The result above gives `NA`, we can easily convert those `NA`'s to 0

```
df1 <- merge(expand.grid(Hair = unique(df$Hair), Eye = unique(df$Eye)), df[-1], 
                                                              all.x = TRUE)
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
```