# How can I copy and append rows of data to fill in missing records in a defined sequence?

Tags: r

I have a sequence of numeric labels for records that can be shared by a variable number of records per label (`labelsequence`).  I also have the records themselves, but unfortunately for some of the sequence values, all records have been lost (dataframe `df`).  I need to identify when a numeric label from `labelsequence` does not appear in the label column of `df`, copy all records within `df` that are associated with the closest label value that is less than the missing value, and append these to a newly filled-in dataframe, say `df2`.

I am trying to accomplish this in R (a dplyr answer would be ideal), and have looked at answers to questions regarding filling in missing rows, such as [Fill in missing rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247211/fill-in-missing-rows-in-r) and [fill missing rows in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944351/fill-missing-rows-in-a-dataframe), and have a working solution below, was wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this.

Take , for instance, this example data:

```
labelsequence<-data.frame(label=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

and

```
df<-data.frame(label=c(1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,4),
           place=c('vermont','kentucky',
                   'wisconsin','wyoming','nevada',
                   'california','utah','georgia','kentucky'),
           animal=c('wolf','wolf','cougar','cougar','lamb',
                    'cougar','donkey','lamb','wolf'))
```

with desired result...

```
desired_df2<-data.frame(label=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6),
            place=c('vermont','kentucky',
                    'wisconsin','wyoming','vermont','kentucky',
                    'wisconsin','wyoming','nevada',
                    'california','utah','georgia','kentucky','utah',
                    'georgia','kentucky','utah','georgia','kentucky'),
            animal=c('wolf','wolf','cougar','cougar','wolf',
                     'wolf','cougar','cougar','lamb','cougar',
                     'donkey','lamb','wolf','donkey','lamb','wolf',
                     'donkey','lamb','wolf'))
```

Is there a better (be it effiency of code, flexibility, or resource efficiency) way than the following?

```
df2<- df %>%
full_join(expand.grid(label=unique(df$label),newlabel=labelsequence$label)) %>%
  mutate(missing = ifelse(newlabel %in% label,0,1))%>%
  filter(label<newlabel)%>%
   group_by(newlabel) %>%
  filter(label==max(label) & missing ==1) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(label=newlabel,missing=NULL,newlabel=NULL) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(label)
```